# How can I get current sheet name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want copy current sheet to new one and sheet name change.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet_name');  <=== question 1
var copy = sourceSheet.copyTo(ss);
ss.setActiveSheet(copy);// set it active
ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());// move it to the last position 
copy.setName(' newSheetName is add 1 from current sheet name'); <== question 2
```

question 1:
 I need current sheet name or ID.

question 2:
 if current sheet name is '10', add 1 for new Sheet name
 I don't know how to add string type of sheet name.

Answer (score 24):

Question 1:

The Id refer to the spreadsheet, the name refer to the sheet. If you want to get the name of the sheet, take a look at the documentation on [sheet.getName() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getName()).

To get the name the active sheet:

```
var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
```

Question 2:

You can use the [substring method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get the last characters of the sourceSheet string and use [parseInt method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to manipulate the characters as int value.

Example: Your sheet's name is '10'. You only need the parseInt method like:

```
var temp = parseInt(sourceSheet);
temp += 1;
copy.setName(temp.toString());
```

Comment: Q1 I don't know.  I need sheet name or index currently being viewed. 
because there are many sheets so, It depends on when user click on a document.
I don't to put any specific numbers or letters here. 
Thanks.

Comment: var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); will get you the name of the active sheet.

Comment: Dont know why, but var actualSheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); always returns the name of the first sheet in the Spreadsheet for me

Comment: @HarshalK It may be cause by the using of getActiveSheet() method who return the active sheet. Take a look at [getSheets() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) to get all the sheets of your spreadsheet and sort them to get the one you looking for.

Comment: @Pierre-MarieRichard You are right. I happen to find out more info on this and turns out that it is kind of a known behavior